# Android ProGuard obfuscation of library: keep class not working

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

**Intro:** I have in AS 1 project with 2 models:

1. Android library project with some "Public API class"
2. Android APP dependent on above library (the library module is on the dependency list)

**Task:** I want to obfuscate my library project because I want to expose it as public SDK but keep my code protected...

**What I did:** So I made custom ProGuard rules:

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-keep class com.org.my_public_api_class_name
```

I skip all other stages in order to eliminate where the bug is to only obfuscation stage.

**Result:** Build of the APP module fails with errors like

`Error: cannot find symbol class my_public_api_class_name`

It seems for me that the problem is that the obfuscation NOT skipped the class I wanted to, so now he has some meaningless name and therefore in the APP, where I'm using him, The original name not exist.

Thanks,

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To exclude your class from obfuscation, try this:

```
 -keep class com.org.my_public_api_class_name**
 -keepclassmembers class com.org.my_public_api_class_name** {*;}
```

Comment: what does the last two asterisk at the end and the `{*;}` means?

Comment: @Mr.Nacho it defines all the Fields and Methods that should be kept (not obfuscated) with * indicating everything and ; showing the end of the current entry. Here is a different entry to show the difference: `-keep class com.org.my_public_api_class_name** { <fields>; <methods>;}`. See the [ProGuard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage)

Comment: I think there should be a . between the my_public_api_class_name and **