# 'Network unreachable' on Play Store published app, but debug version works

Tags: java, android, google-play, proguard

I cannot connect to my Chromecast Audio using the Play Store published version of my app, but I can on the USB-debugging version on the same phone. Both versions can access the network, i.e. they both successfully find the IP address of the Chromecast device.

Same phone, Chromecast, network and code. It's just the Play Store published APK/Bundle that cannot connect.

In the Logcat I see:

```
2019-05-27 11:05:12.753 9203-9370/? W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.100.109 (port 8009) from /:: (port 0): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.753 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:138)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.753 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.753 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:357)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.753 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:201)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.753 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:183)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.753 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.753 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.753 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.connect(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:263)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.connect(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:250)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at f.a.a.a.a.y.connect(Unknown Source:55)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at f.a.a.a.a.y.d(Unknown Source:4)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at f.a.a.a.a.z.a(Unknown Source:28)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at f.a.a.a.a.z.j(Unknown Source:5)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at f.a.a.a.a.z.e(Unknown Source:0)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at [my app's name].j.e(Unknown Source:29)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at [my app's name].j.b(Unknown Source:0)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at [my app's name].f.run(Unknown Source:3)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:126)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:152)
2019-05-27 11:05:12.754 9203-9370/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
```

Clearly, my app can access the network as it finds the AVR/Chromecast Audio's IP address (192.168.100.109). I have also given it INTERNET permission in the manifest. I am also using `minifyEnabled true` and `shrinkResources true` in my build.gradle file.

I am using [ChromeCast Java API v2](https://github.com/vitalidze/chromecast-java-api-v2) for convenience, rather than the official [Cast SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/), if this makes any difference.

EDIT: Solved. It was the option `minifyEnabled true` in the `build.gradle (Module: app)` file (i.e. ProGuard) not liking the [ChromeCast Java API v2](https://github.com/vitalidze/chromecast-java-api-v2) library.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/discovery

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't see anything helpful there though. The debug and the published version are both exactly the same code. Yet the only one that works is the debug version that is loaded onto my phone via USB from Android Studio.

Comment: Did check you api keys ? Because there is a difference between release and debug version

Comment: Thanks. I haven't needed an API key. All I needed was to register with Google and create a Chromecast Receiver app on their website, and then pass the App ID to the Chromecast Java API v2 `chromecast` object. It seems to me that the functions in the library cannot access the network on the Published version.

Comment: Great so let me know to post it as answer

Comment: It's definitely the `minifyEnabled true` that caused it. ProGuard doesn't like [Chromecast Java API v2](https://github.com/vitalidze/chromecast-java-api-v2), so added exclusions to my proguard-rules.pro file: `-keep class su.litvak.chromecast.**` and `-keepclassmembers class su.litvak.chromecast.** {*;}` thanks to the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648365/android-proguard-obfuscation-of-library-keep-class-not-working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the option `minifyEnabled true` in the `build.gradle (Module: app)` file was the problem. ProGuard and the [ChromeCast Java API v2](https://github.com/vitalidze/chromecast-java-api-v2) library don't work well together, so one needs to add exclusions to the `proguard-rules.pro` file if one wants to use the minifyEnabled option:

```
-keep class su.litvak.chromecast.**
-keepclassmembers class su.litvak.chromecast.** {*;}
```

Many thanks to the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648365/android-proguard-obfuscation-of-library-keep-class-not-working) by user [random](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193545/random).